# How to sort an integer list in Python in descending order

Tags: python, list

I have tried to figure this out in different ways, without any success.  I keep getting an ascending order sort, rather than descending order when I print.

```
ListB = [24, 13, -15, -36, 8, 22, 48, 25, 46, -9]
sorted(ListB, key=int, reverse=True)
print sorted(ListB)
```

Comment: `reversed(sorted(listb))`

Comment: You typed `print sorted(ListB)`, which, quite naturally, prints `ListB` sorted.

Comment: Related: *[Sort a list of numerical strings in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758959/)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are printing the list sorted ascending:

```
print sorted(ListB)
```

If you want it descending, put your print statement on the previous line (where you reverse it)

```
print sorted(ListB, key=int, reverse=True)
```

Then remove your final print statement.

Example:

```
>>> ListB = [24, 13, -15, -36, 8, 22, 48, 25, 46, -9]
>>> print sorted(ListB, key=int, reverse=True)
[48, 46, 25, 24, 22, 13, 8, -9, -15, -36]
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this. It'll sort the list in-place in descending order (there isn't any need to specify a key in this case):

```
listB = [24, 13, -15, -36, 8, 22, 48, 25, 46, -9]
listB.sort(reverse=True) # listB gets modified

print listB
=> [48, 46, 25, 24, 22, 13, 8, -9, -15, -36]
```

Alternatively, you can create a new sorted list:

```
listB = [24, 13, -15, -36, 8, 22, 48, 25, 46, -9]
listC = sorted(listB, reverse=True) # listB remains untouched

print listC
=> [48, 46, 25, 24, 22, 13, 8, -9, -15, -36]
```

Comment: Your suggestion is a good one since I will eventually need a new list.  I am teaching myself Python by manually creating a box and whisker plot.  Sorting the list is important.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
ListB = [24, 13, -15, -36, 8, 22, 48, 25, 46, -9]

ListB = sorted(ListB, key=int, reverse=True)

print ListB
```

Sorted does not change the variable passed to it. So if you want to do anything with them you have to store sorted output into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
reversed(sorted(listb))
```

This creates an iterable going from 48 -> -36

Comment: just reversed(ListB).

Answer (score 0):

You should have combined these two lines of code together, using this instead.

```
print sorted(ListB, key=int, reverse=True)
```

Result:

```
[48, 46, 25, 24, 22, 13, 8, -9, -15, -36]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can sort as follows:

```
listA = [150, 120, 100, 165, 190, 145, 182, 175, 17]
print(sorted(listA))
print(sorted(listA, reverse=True))
```

This would be the actual implementation using [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort):

```
# Traverse through all array elements
for i in range(len(listA)):

    # Find the minimum element in remaining
    # unsorted array
    min_idx = i
    for j in range(i + 1, len(listA)):
        if listA[min_idx] > listA[j]:
            min_idx = j

    # Swap the found minimum element with
    # the first element
    listA[i], listA[min_idx] = listA[min_idx], listA[i]

print(listA)

# Traverse through all array elements
for i in range(len(listA)):

    # Find the minimum element in remaining
    # unsorted array
    min_idx = i
    for j in range(i + 1, len(listA)):
        if listA[min_idx] < listA[j]:
            min_idx = j

    # Swap the found minimum element with
    # the first element
    listA[i], listA[min_idx] = listA[min_idx], listA[i]

print(listA)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ListB = [24, 13, -15, -36, 8, 22, 48, 25, 46, -9]
ListB.sort()
print(ListB[::-1])
```

This should work