# Dealing with four digits: memcache sorts 1000 before 150 from least to greatest

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

In app engine I retrieve a list of items stored in memcache:

```
items = memcache.get("ITEMS")
```

and sort them by amount and price:

```
items.sort(key = lambda x:(x.price, x.amount))
```

Which works most of the time, when the amount is three digits. However, when I have 2 items with 150 and 1000 amounts for the same price, the entry with 1000 goes before other one. How can I fix this?

Comment: Asked and answered: 
Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/numeric-sort-in-python
Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3426155/2225787

Answer (score 0):

fixed it:

```
items.sort(key = lambda x:((float)(x.price), (int)(x.amount)))
```