# Python disregarding zeros when sorting numbers in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a list of dollar amounts from lowest to highest using python's built in sort ability, but when I call on it, it sorts the numbers super screwy. It starts at $10,000 then goes up to $19,0000 (which is the highest) then jumps down to $2,000 and counts up from there ostensibly because 2 is bigger than 1. I don't know how to correct for this. The code I've used is below.

```
numbers=[['$10014.710000000001'], ['$10014.83'],['$11853.300000000001'],
['$19060.010000000006'],['$2159.1099999999997'],['$3411.1400000000003']]

print(sorted(numbers))
```

Comment: its because your "numbers" are not numbers and poor python has to Lexicographical sort the strings. want numerical sort, you'd need to temporarily convert to numbers for sorting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/how-to-sort-a-list-numerically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a list numerically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/how-to-sort-a-list-numerically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key insight here is that the values in your list are actually strings, and strings are compared lexically: each character in the string is compared one at a time until the first non-matching character. So "aa" sorts before "ab", but that also means that "a1000" sorts before "a2". If you want to sort in a different way, you need to tell the `sort` method (or the `sorted` function) what it is you want to sort by.

In this case, you probably should use the `decimal` module. And you want the `key` attribute of the `sort` method. This will sort the existing list you have, only using the converted values during the sorting process.

```
import decimal

def extract_sortable_value(value):
    # value is a list, so take the first element
    first_value = value[0]
    return decimal.Decimal(first_value.lstrip('$'))

numbers.sort(key=extract_sortable_value)
```

Equivalently, you could do:

```
print(sorted(numbers, key=extract_sortable_value))
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/MiserableDarkPatches

Answer (score 2):

You are not sorting numbers but strings, which explains the "weird" result. Instead, change your type to float and sort the resulting list:

```
In [3]: sorted([[float(el[0][1:])] for el in numbers])
Out[3]: 
[[2159.1099999999997],
 [3411.1400000000003],
 [10014.710000000001],
 [10014.83],
 [11853.300000000001],
 [19060.010000000006]]
```

I need the `el[0]` because every number is inside its own list, which is not a good style, but I guess you have your reasons for this. The `[1:]` strips away the `$` sign.

**EDIT** really good point made in the comments. More robust solution:

```
from decimal import Decimal

import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 4

sorted([Decimal(el[0][1:]) for el in numbers])
Out[8]: 
[Decimal('2159.1099999999997'),
 Decimal('3411.1400000000003'),
 Decimal('10014.710000000001'),
 Decimal('10014.83'),
 Decimal('11853.300000000001'),
 Decimal('19060.010000000006')]
```

Comment: Yes, the list within a list formatting is due to some other functions I have to perform with the data. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: If you don't want this kind of encapsulation in the sorted list, just change `sorted([[float(el[0][1:])] for el in numbers])` to `sorted([float(el[0][1:]) for el in numbers])` :)

Comment: Don't use `float` for currency values!

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers are currency values. So as pointed out in the comments below, it might make sense to use Python's [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) module which offers several advantages over the `float` datatype. (See link for further information.)

---

If, however, this is only an exercise for better getting to know Python, as I suspect. You might look for a simpler solution:

The reason, why your sorting doesn't work, is because your numbers are stored in the list inside another list as a string. You have to convert them to integers or floats before sorting has the effect you're looking for:

```
numbers=[
    ['$10014.710000000001'],
    ['$10014.83'],
    ['$11853.300000000001'],
    ['$19060.010000000006'],
    ['$2159.1099999999997'],
    ['$3411.1400000000003']
]

numbers_float = [float(number[0][1:]) for number in numbers]
numbers_float.sort()

print(numbers_float)
```

Which prints:

```
[2159.1099999999997, 3411.1400000000003, 10014.710000000001, 10014.83, 11853.300000000001, 19060.010000000006]
```

When you look at `float(number[0][1:])`, then `[0]` takes the first (and only) number of your (inner) number list, `[1:]` strips the `$` sign and finally `float` does the conversion to floating point number.

If you want the `$` sign back:

```
for number in numbers_float:
    print("${}".format(number))
```

Which prints:

```
$2159.1099999999997
$3411.1400000000003
$10014.710000000001
$10014.83
$11853.300000000001
$19060.010000000006
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'll give that a shot. Thanks very much!

Comment: Don't use `float` for currency values, since it doesn't round the same way decimal numbers round. You probably want to use the `decimal` module instead.

Comment: @DanielPryden I highly suspect that this is not necessary here but you're definitely right to mention it. Doesn't hurt, so I added it to the answer as a disclaimer.