# How do you sort a list of numbers which are strings in python?

Tags: python, sorting

this is more than likely a duplicate question, however all my searches were unsuccessful in helping me. Anyways, I would like to sort this list from the largest number to the smallest number, yet it consistently prints None. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
list = ['1008', '1033', '1080', '3107', '3589', '574', '703', '704', '712', '731', '810', '857', '862', '909', '927', '980']

print(list.sort()) # Prints None
```

Comment: `list.sort()` doesn't return anything you need to call `list.sort()` then print the list `print(list)`

Comment: For string values **sort** consider ASCII value. Try this **list.sort(key=int)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: Can you rephrase the title? It’s difficult to understand. Also, don’t name a variable `list`.

Comment: @AMC For the first question, that was one of the guides I found when trying to fix this issue and it didn't really work. Second, I did change the title, hopefully its a tad bit better, haha (I'm bad at wording things). Finally, this is just a small portion of a larger code, and is'nt actually named list in there.

Comment: @Bigc1109 What do you mean by _it didn’t really work_ ?

Comment: @aleemmd How do ASCII values relate to the rest of your comment, though?

Comment: @AMC The answer given on there only worked with the list already in integers. I didn't realize this was the issue with my code until I posted this.

Comment: @Bigc1109 Did you not know how to parse an int from a string? Either way, I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @AMC I do know how to change a string into an integer, but as I said before, I didn't know that was the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of strings numerically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-numerically)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
list = ['1008', '1033', '1080', '3107', '3589', '574', '703', '704', '712', '731', '810', '857', '862', '909', '927', '980']

for i in range(0, len(list)): 
    list[i] = int(list[i])

list.sort(reverse = True) 
print(list)

'''
```

Comment: Note that the elements in the list are strings. They'd need to be converted to integers first!

Comment: Whoops, let me fix that!

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. However, is there anyway to change the list of strings into integers without changing the actual list? As in keep the list as strings and update the list to change it to integers?

Comment: Yep! Create a new array on the side, let me add it in to my answer

Comment: Actually having trouble adding it to my answer, for unfortunately I must go. If you can complete it on your own, well done, but I'll finish the entire code tomorrow. And of course!

Comment: Naming a variable `list` is a bad idea. Why iterate over the indices of the list if all you do is access the element at the current index?

Comment: Oh, and `0` is the default value for the `start` parameter in `range()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is doing inline sort. You have to try either of below approaches.

> Python lists have a built-in sort() method that modifies the list
>   in-place and a sorted() built-in function that builds a new sorted
>   list from an iterable.

```
list.sort()
print(list)
```

or

```
print(sorted(list))
```

Your List is of character strings. First you have to convert them to integers and then sort.

```
>>> list
['1008', '1033', '1080', '3107', '3589', '574', '703', '704', '712', '731', '810', '857', '862', '909', '927', '980']
>>> int_list = [int(l) for l in list]
>>> int_list.sort()
>>> int_list
[574, 703, 704, 712, 731, 810, 857, 862, 909, 927, 980, 1008, 1033, 1080, 3107, 3589]
```

Or Simply you can do as below:

```
>>> print(sorted(list,key=int))
```

Comment: This does fix the issue of printing the actual list. However, for some reason it is still not being sorted. Both of these print it the same way as it is in the list.

Comment: I got it. It was list of characters. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sorted((int(i) for i in list),reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are sorting the list of strings you can pass `int` as key to sort function, so it will call `int()` for every string in the list.

```
list = ['1008', '1033', '1080', '3107', '3589', '574', '703', '704', '712', '731', '810', '857', '862', '909', '927', '980']
list.sort(key=int)
print(list)
```