# How to sort user input list elements?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to get a list input by the user and then sort the list elements (which are integers) in ascending order. But the elements are stored as strings and I don't know how to convert each element into `int` type. For example:

```
p = input("Enter comma separated numbers:")
p = p.split(",")
p.sort()
print(p)
```

When I input

```
-9,-3,-1,-100,-4
```

I get the result as:

```
['-1', '-100', '-3', '-4', '-9']
```

But the desired output is:

```
[-100, -9, -4, -3, -1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `p` is a list that consists of strings therefore they won't be sorted by their numerical values. Try this:

```
p.sort(key=int)
```

If you need a list of integers, convert them in the beginning:

```
p = [int(i) for i in p.split(",")]
```

Comment: Yes this works! Can you provide me some details on p.sort(**key=int**), some link or so?

Comment: I suggest you to read the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) first. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426120/2011147) (which happens to be a duplicate of your question) might help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try `p = list(map(int, p.split(",")))` instead of your second line, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

`input("blabla")` returns string values even if you are inputting numbers. When you are sorting p, you are not sorting integers like you think.

This piece of code converts string elements of a list to integers, you can do this first then sort the new integer array:

```
 for i in range(0,len(p)):
        p[i] = int(p[i])
```

or in easier way you can turn string elements to integers while splitting the string by using int parameter, as zack256 mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input()
p = a.split(',')
p.sort(key=int)
print(p)

a = input("type--")
p = list(a.split(','))
p.reverse()
print(p)
```